# How do I get my async function to return values not a promise?

Tags: node.js, typescript, async-await

I am new to async/await functionality. I have a function that the gets db info and I'd like to make the function `setUpDb()` wait until the promise is completed before returning.

```
const dbInfo = this.setUpDb();
console.log(dbInfo);

async setUpDb() {
    const appLoc = path.join(homedir(), ".tsa"); // temp db info
    const f: string = path.join(appLoc, "config.json");
    await fs.ensureFile(f);
    const temp = await fs.readJson(f);
    console.log(temp);
    return {
        dbHost: temp.dbHost,
        dbUser: temp.dbUser,
        dbPass: temp.dbPass
    };
}
```

My current output is: `Promise { <pending> }` then a moment later it's all the info in `temp`.

I just need to get the return to wait until there are values before it returns. Is that possible?

Thanks!!

Comment: All JavaScript functions return synchronously. You can't get them to wait to return without something like a spinlock that blocks the whole event-loop. `async` just makes them return a Promise, but they still return before any async code has run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're logging before the async function completes. Just wait for the promise to resolve before logging it

```
let dbInfo;
this.setUpDb().then(result => {
  dbInfo = result;
  console.log(dbInfo);
});
```

Comment: Awesome! that works. Thanks. Is there a way to get the information outside the .then() ? I'll update my question to make it more clear.

Comment: You're using async code, so the CONSUMING part of the app has to be able to handle waiting for the async script to finish. The only way to avoid using `.then` is to use `await`, which would require the consuming part of the app to also be running in an async method

Comment: Yeah, I've been getting that impression. Just wasn't sure if it was possible. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 2):

You must await for the return of `setUpDb` function

```
async setup() {
    const dbInfo = await this.setUpDb();
    console.log(dbInfo);
}

async setUpDb() {
    const appLoc = path.join(homedir(), ".tsa"); // temp db info
    const f: string = path.join(appLoc, "config.json");
    await fs.ensureFile(f);
    const temp = await fs.readJson(f);
    console.log(temp);
    return {
        dbHost: temp.dbHost,
        dbUser: temp.dbUser,
        dbPass: temp.dbPass
    };
}
```

Comment: Yeah that's also an option. I have used that in the past in fact.

Answer (score 1):

I think Asthmatic suggestion is the best way, but I think you can also do..

```
//const temp = await fs.readJson(f);
let temp;
await() => temp = fs.readJson(f);
```

(I may be wrong)